# Unable to indicate the html id for password field and not able to login to the page using Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]Trying to login to an Intranet site using WinForms and C#.

**Following is the code for login -**

```
webbrowserObject.Document.GetElementById("USER").SetAttribute("value", Properties.Settings.Default.UserEmail);
webbrowserObject.Document.GetType("password").SetAttribute("Value", Properties.Settings.Default.UserPassword);
webbrowserObject.Document.GetElementById("loginbtn").InvokeMember("submit");
```

**Getting following error -**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'GetType' takes 1 arguments
```

**And when I am changing the code as below -**

```
 webbrowserObject.Document.GetElementById("USER").SetAttribute("value", Properties.Settings.Default.UserEmail);
 webbrowserObject.Document.GetElementById("PASSWORD").SetAttribute("Value", Properties.Settings.Default.UserPassword);
 webbrowserObject.Document.GetElementById("loginbtn").InvokeMember("submit");
 while (!DocumentLoaded)
```

**Following is the error -**

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

**Following are the html information of the Site that I am trying to login to -**

```
<input name="USER" class="form-control textbox center-block noborder " id="USER" autofocus="" required="" type="text" placeholder="User ID">
<input name="PASSWORD" class="form-control textbox  center-block noborder" required="" onkeydown="return FormKeyPressed();" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: `GetType()` has nothing to do with filtering html elements. Use `GetElementsByTagName()`: `dim passwordElement = webbrowserObject.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").OfType(Of HtmlElement).FirstOrDefault(Function(elm) elm.GetAttribute("name").Contains("PASSWORD"))`, then set the value to this element if not null (written here, check the syntax).

Comment: The `NullReferenceException` error could be occurring for any element you are trying to use; user input, password input, or the login button.

Comment: The reason why I posted it in VB.Net is unknown. `var passwordElement = webbrowserObject.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(elm =>  elm.GetAttribute("name").Contains("PASSWORD");`. In your edit, `Document.GetElementById("PASSWORD")` will fail since the `Password` `INPUT` element doesn't have an ID attribute.

Comment: @quaabaam I have added the image of exception. It looks like issues with the Password as the code is not able to capture the "Password" field from the elements.

Comment: @Jimi, Is this possible to click "Tab" key using Code after entering Username? This way the curser will go to "Password" and then I can enter the Password programatically.

Comment: @AnuragThakur from the image you posted, it's the `user` control where the null reference exception is occurring.

Comment: You don't need to *tab* anything. Use the code that I posted. The `Password` `<INPUT>` element doesn't have an ID attribute, so you get it using `GetElementsByTagName`, filtering the elements in the collection using another attribute, the `name` or `type`, in this case.